# How can I update a multi value combo box in ms access vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I need to know how to update the value of a multi-value combo box in MS Access?  I have a continuous form where each record contains a multi-select combo box.  What I'm needing to do is do an UPDATE of all Similar records on the form in the `AfterUpdate()` proc of that combo box.

I'm currently doing this with UPDATE sql on a form that has a regular combo box.  However, I get an error stating "An UPDATE or DELETE query cannot contain a multi-valued field."  So I need another option.

I can simply run a loop through the records in the recordset, but I was hoping for a more eloquent solution. :-)

Thoughts?

Comment: I would not use multi-value fields unless you are using Sharepoint. All they do is make life difficult. If you really must, read up a little http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-HA010149297.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I found the answer....

DON'T USE MULTI-VALUE COMBO BOXES!!!

...now to redesign....